# What axioms are necessary to prove Mostowski Collapse?

Tags: set-theory

I've been reading Schimmerling's *A Course on Set Theory*, and have been enjoying it a lot so far. However, some times he's less clear than I think he could be. For example, during a proof of Mostowski collapse (specifically, he's trying to prove that, if $\langle A, \prec \rangle$ is a well-ordering, then there is an ordinal $\alpha$ and an isomorphism $\pi$ such that $\pi : \langle A, \prec \rangle \simeq \langle \alpha, < \rangle$), he states (p. 39):

"Without assuming that $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $\pi$ is an isomorphism, recursively define $\pi : A \rightarrow B$ by setting $\pi(y) = \{\pi(x) \; | \; x \prec y\}$. This is not entirely legitimate, at least not if we wish to implement Theorem 3.8 [i.e. if we wish to implement a recursive definition], because we are required to name the set $B$ before we define $\pi$ by recursion. We will leave out the argument that we can choose $B$ in advance since it involves reasoning from the axioms of ZFC that is overly technical from the perspective of this book."

Now, I'm really curious as to what is involved in this "overly technical" argument, as Schimmerling doesn't even provide a sketch. What are the axioms involved? And how does one go about proving that we can "choose $B$ in advance"? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Schimmerling does proceed to explain how to define the collapse in the remaining pages of this section, by showing, well, that $\pi$ is an isomorphism and that $\pi[A]$ is an ordinal, but he never attempts to show that the range of $\pi$ is well defined in the first place. I thought that this might involve Replacement; can I show that by $\in$-induction instead (or also)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you mean transfinite recursion by $\in$-induction?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry to be a pain, but do you have a reference for it? Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, right! I'm pretty sure ${\it that's}$ not equivalent to replacement, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Any $V_\lambda$, for $\lambda$ a limit, models $Z$, but not all such models model ZF. Just to be clear, regularity says that $\in$ is well-founded.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know, which is why I'm so perplexed. So you agree now that given that $V_\lambda$ models ZF - replacement, regularity, or $\in$-induction, is not equivalent to replacement? (Sorry, I was taking Z to be ZF - replacement, and ZF to be formulated with both replacement and separation, although strictly the latter is redundant).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm pretty sure we must be talking past one another. In two of your comments, you said that $\in$-induction is equivalent to replacement. The simple model I gave you, which you obviously know well, shows that isn't true. That's all I'm claiming.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I know that replacement implies transfinite induction, but do you have a reference which shows that transfinite induction implies replacement (I'm not being facetious, I'm genuinely curious)? In any case, going back to the original question, if I define $\pi(y) = \{\pi(x)\;|\;x \prec y \}$, can I apply replacement directly in order to define $B$? If so, what's so "overly technical" about that?

Comment: @Nagase Good idea, a reference would be nice at this point. That any $V_\lambda$ satisfies $\in$-induction seems pretty trivial to me - using $\in$-induction in the ambient theory. Also, you're right - there's nothing technical in getting $B$. And we don't need to specify such a set in order to apply transfinite recursion. I'm really not sure what Schimmerling had in mind here (unless he just means to say that the proof of transfinite recursion is a little fiddly, which is true).

Comment: I have a headache and the repetition is not helping. As for a reference, I don't have one of the top of my head. If I'll have an idea, I'll let you know. I recall this isn't a difficult proof, though. Assume that transfinite induction holds, and let $\varphi$ be a functional formula, and you somehow bound the range and apply separation (or something like that).

Comment: @GME: Well, it's a little bit weird, because Schimmerling had already proved transfinite recursion previously in the book. So I'm also a little bit at loss with his remarks.

Comment: @Nagase I see. I guess he may well be right that one can't assume there is such a $B$ ${\it before}$ one does the transfinite recursion - but there's really no need to. Just do it, then apply replacement, as you say.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No worries! I agree that the repetition is at this point unproductive. Obviously a reference or proof would settle the matter. So, do let me know if you find a reference or a proof! Thanks again!

Comment: @GME: Maybe for some reason he thought that applying replacement was a "overly technical" (I don't quite remember he using replacement before, which may show a certain unwillingness to use it).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks for the help, anyway. I'll try to find a reference on this issue (transfinite induction --> replacement) as well.

Comment: @Nagase Perhaps. Though if he proved transfinite recursion, he would have had to use it. Anyway, do let me know if you get a reference on the other question!

Comment: @GME: Actually, I just checked the book and noticed that he only proves the recursion theorem, but not transfinite recursion. Again, he says that the proof would be "overly technical" (same expression!), so he prefers to only give examples. That's probably it, then.

Comment: @GME - I don't know if you're still interested on the issue, but Joel David Hamkins has just posted a proof that (in the presence of choice) replacement is indeed equivalent to transfinite recursion. Interestingly, he also mentions a connection to Mostowski's theorem. See here: http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-recursion-as-a-fundamental-principle-in-set-theory/

Comment: @Nagase Thanks for this! I've actually seen Benjamin give a talk of this stuff before!

Answer (score 1):

On p.76 of "[In Praise of Replacement](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41472440)" (Bulletin of Symbolic Logic vol. 18 no. 1, 2012), Kanamori states:

> Mathias [2001b] showed that over KP + Power Set + Choice, $\Sigma_1$-Separation is equivalent to every well-ordering of a set being order-isomorphic to an ordinal.